# node-fetch with ipv6 proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, ipv6, node-fetch

Do you know any way to use node-fetch (or similar package), with an ipv6 proxy ? I'm stuck on this "small" point.

I tried to

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

class Something {
  async init (url) {
    return fetch(url, {agent: new HttpsProxyAgent('https://2a01:cb00:8612:c000:86d:5188:7abc:4c2f')})
      .then(res => res.text())
    }
}
```

But was not working (surprise...)

Got:

```
failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 2a01
```

I'm sure that I'm making something stupid, but i don't understand what i can do or not with ipv6...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly formatting the IPv6 address literal in your URL. You need to surround the IPv6 address with brackets (`[` and `]`):

```
https://[2a01:cb00:8612:c000:86d:5188:7abc:4c2f]
```

This is explained in [RFC 2732, Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt):

> 2.Literal IPv6 Address Format in URL's Syntax
>
> To use a literal IPv6 address in a URL, the literal address should be
> enclosed in "[" and "]" characters.  For example the following literal
> IPv6 addresses:
>
> ```
>   FEDC:BA98:7654:3210:FEDC:BA98:7654:3210
>   1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:4171
>   3ffe:2a00:100:7031::1
>   1080::8:800:200C:417A
>   ::192.9.5.5
>   ::FFFF:129.144.52.38
>   2010:836B:4179::836B:4179
> ```
>
> would be represented as in the following example URLs:
>
> ```
>   http://[FEDC:BA98:7654:3210:FEDC:BA98:7654:3210]:80/index.html
>   http://[1080:0:0:0:8:800:200C:417A]/index.html
>   http://[3ffe:2a00:100:7031::1]
>   http://[1080::8:800:200C:417A]/foo
>   http://[::192.9.5.5]/ipng
>   http://[::FFFF:129.144.52.38]:80/index.html
>   http://[2010:836B:4179::836B:4179]
> ```